# Unhandled promise rejection: NotAllowedError: Write permission denied Angular unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a function that includes a timeout function + copies a text from the clipboard:

```
  copyLink(linkAddress: string, index: number) {
    this.showTickForCopiedLink[index] = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.showTickForCopiedLink[index] = false;
    }, 800); 
    return navigator.clipboard.writeText(linkAddress);
  }
```

I am trying to write a test for this function:

```
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [SideBarNoteComponent],
  providers: [Clipboard],
  }).compileComponents();
}));
    
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SideBarNoteComponent);
 component = fixture.componentInstance;
 fixture.detectChanges();
}));   
it('show tick icon for copied link for 800ms and then hide it', 
 fakeAsync(() => {
  component.showTickForCopiedLink = [
  false,
  false,
  false,
 ];
 component.copyLink('link1', 1);
 expect(component.showTickForCopiedLink[1]).toBeTrue();
 tick(799);
 expect(component.showTickForCopiedLink[1]).toBeTrue();
 tick(2);
 expect(component.showTickForCopiedLink[1]).toBeFalse();
}));
```

The test passes when running on its own, but when I run all the tests for the project, I get the error:

```
An error was thrown in afterAll

Unhandled promise rejection: NotAllowedError: Write permission denied.
```

How can I write the right tests for this function?

Comment: Is there a stack trace? If yes, please add it to the question. It helps narrowing down the cause of the error.

Comment: @JSONDerulo what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to mock your global object. You're providing some clipboard service, but in reality you do not use this service in your component, that's why it's not working for you.

You could spy on the browser implementation in your test by adjusting the code

```js
const spy = jasmine.spyOn(navigator.clipboard, 'writeText');

// run your test

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(/* your call value /*)
```

Comment: I already have a test for spying on navigator.clipboard (I did not add it to the post because I thought it would be irrelevant data). But the one that makes the tests fail is the 'show tick icon for copied link for 800ms and then hide it' one.

Comment: This is not test for navigator.clipboard. This is to stub the real implementation so that it's not called. `toHaveBeenCalledWith` check is optional just to verify the complete method flow. Spy is the key to prevent the test from invoking the real implementation